# Variance when T needs to be in covariant and contravariant position

Tags: scala

Here is my problem, I have a typeclass defined like this :

```
trait Alterer[T] {
  def alter(t: T): T
}

object Alterer {
  implicit val stringPrinter = new Alterer[String]{
    override def alter(s: String) =  "hi " + s
  }
}

object Alter {
  def alter[T](obj: T)(implicit alterer: Alterer[T]) = alterer.alter(obj)
}

val bob2 = Alter.alter("bob") // hi bob
```

Now I want to define implicit instances for other types.
But I 'd like to be able to define for a supertype. Example with Any as supertype :

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

implicit val anyPrinter = new Alterer[Any]{
  override def alter(a: Any) = ("hi any " + a.toString)
}

Alter.alter(Person("joe", 34))
```

This will not compile because my T type needs to be contravariant if I want a Alterer[Any] to be seen as a Alterer[Person].

So I would do something like :

```
trait Alterer[-T] {
   def alter(t: T): T
}
```

It would be OK if the alter method was not also returning a T. 
Here the compiler complains because T return type is not in contravariant position.

Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: The typical way is to add a type parameter like `TT <: T` or `TT >: T` depending on which part of the signature is having the variance problem. If we try that here, we'll get other errors because the wrong types will be expected, which really stems from trying to make `T => T` vary in one direction while the argument/return type vary in the opposite direction of each other. That is, using an `Any => Any` instead of a `T => T` for some `T` will rarely, if ever, be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two type parameters for this, one for the contravariant input and one for the covariant output.

```
trait Alterer[-T, +U] {
   def alter(t: T): U
}
```

Then you can declare a

```
  implicit val stringPrinter = new Alterer[String, String]{
    override def alter(s: String) =  "hi " + s
  }
```

For strings or

```
implicit val anyPrinter = new Alterer[Any, String]{
  override def alter(a: Any) = ("hi any " + a.toString)
}
```

Which converts an Any to a string and preprends "hi any "

If you wanted to enforce a subtype relationship between the input and output you could instead of your trait use an abstract class that takes in a subtype evidence in its constructor.

```
abstract class Alterer[-T, +U](implicit ev: U <:< T) {
  def alter(t: T): U
}
```

`<:<` is defined in predef and enforces that U is a subtype of T.

The rest of this code remains identical after this change.